# Select Rows From One Table, Where Matching Rows in Another Table Has Empty Column

Tags: postgresql, select, where

I have multiple Postgres tables that look like the following. They are generated on a daily basis, so each just represents the data that was processed for that day:

**data_20200113**

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
|  account  |  name  |    id    |
+-----------+--------+----------+
|  0011223  |  Jeff  |  apple   |
|  0033445  |  Bill  |  pear    |
|  0055667  |  Drew  |  orange  |
|  0077889  |  Ted   |  peach   |
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

**data_20200114**

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
|  account  |  name  |    id    |
+-----------+--------+----------+
|  0011223  |  Jeff  |          |
|  0033445  |  Bill  |  pear    |
|  0055667  |  Drew  |          |
|  0077889  |  Ted   |  peach   |
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

The end goal that I'm trying to get to is a single query in which I'm returned all of the rows from the former table, which now show a blank in that final "id" column in the latter table. The result would hopefully look like something in the below:

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
|  account  |  name  |    id    |
+-----------+--------+----------+
|  0011223  |  Jeff  |  apple   |
|  0055667  |  Drew  |  orange  |
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Will the account/ name mappings ever change? Will the same accounts/ names be in every day's list and no new ones ever appear or old ones disappear?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a simple EXISTS condition

```
select *
from data_20200113 d1
where exists (select *
              from data_20200114 d2
              where (d1.account, d1.name) = (d2.account, d2.name) 
                and d2.id is null);
```

Comment: Why not use an `INNER JOIN` - see my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=768dd62be31caf431b69eb9988630767)? Is the performance of `EXISTS` better?

Comment: @Vérace: because an inner join can return duplicate rows if there are multiple matches

Answer (score 0):

There is a smaller variant to do the same:

```
select a.*
from data_20200113 a, data_20200114 b
where b.account=a.account and b.id is null
```

Maybe you like it more than the previous variant? :-)

Comment: Please learn to use the "modern" (over 25 years old) explicit `JOIN` operators rather than using the fragile and ancient implicit joins in the WHERE clause (and your join should include the `number` column as well)

Comment: Ha-ha-ha, very funny :-)
SQL processor decides itself which execution plan has to be used, there are almost no difference of which form you use when writing the query.
Thus you can write your query in any form you prefer, the result will be the same.

Comment: It's not about performance, but readability and robustness. Plus: it's the only way to specify other join types (outer join, later joins)

Comment: Yes, as for me, simple multiplication is more readable and robust

Comment: Well, actually the explicit JOIN is more robust as it's impossible to forget a join condition which can happen quite easily with the outdated syntax https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: OK, no worries, let your variant be the best, keep calm and be happy! :-)